stim: enhancing performance measuring Pauli strings without keeping the outcome
I have the following question. If I perform projective measurements of a given (multi-qubit) Pauli string in my TableauSimulator I implicitly perform some Gaussian-elimination steps to get the measurement result ($\pm 1$). If I'm not wrong, this should have some possible $O(n^3)$ complexity steps.
Nevertheless, I'm studying a problem where the outcome information is unnecessary. In this case, I expect that I can simply avoid these result-revealing steps and simply compute the new generators a la Aaronson and Gottesman.
In this case, updating the destabilizer tableau would be unnecessary. Hence we can just focus on a TableauHalf object.
I was going through the C++ source but did not find an already implemented function on the Tableau or TableauSimulator headers. Hence, I implemented a version looping over the TableauHalf and updating it according to this paper.
uint64_t popcnt(uint64_t x) {
  uint64_t count = x;
  count = (count & 0x5555555555555555) + ((count >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555);
  count = (count & 0x3333333333333333) + ((count >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333);
  count = (count & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f) + ((count >> 4) & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f);
  count = (count & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ff) + ((count >> 8) & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ff);
  count = (count & 0x0000ffff0000ffff) + ((count >> 16) & 0x0000ffff0000ffff);
  count = (count & 0x00000000ffffffff) + ((count >> 32) & 0x00000000ffffffff);
  return count;
}

template <size_t W>
void measure_pauli(const size_t num_qubits, TableauHalf<W> &T, const PauliStringRef<W> P) {
    size_t pivot=-1;
    std::vector<size_t> indices;
    size_t n = P.xs.num_u64_padded();
    for (size_t w = 0; w < n; w++) {
        uint64_t v = P.xs.u64[w] | P.zs.u64[w];
        if (v>0) {
            indices.push_back(w);
        }
    }
    for (size_t q1 = 0; q1 < num_qubits; q1++) {
        PauliStringRef<MAX_BITWORD_WIDTH> z1 = T[q1];
        size_t test =0;
        for (size_t & v : indices){
            test+= popcnt((z1.zs.u64[v]&P.xs.u64[v])^(z1.xs.u64[v]&P.zs.u64[v]));
        }
        if (test%2) {
            pivot=q1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (pivot>=0) {
        T[pivot]= P;
        for (size_t q2 = pivot + 1; q2 < num_qubits; q2++) {
            PauliStringRef<MAX_BITWORD_WIDTH> z1 = T[q2];
            size_t test =0;
            for (size_t & v : indices){
                test+= popcnt((z1.zs.u64[v]&P.xs.u64[v])^(z1.xs.u64[v]&P.zs.u64[v]));
            }
            if (test%2){
                for (size_t & v : indices){
                    z1.xs.u64[v] ^= P.xs.u64[v];
                    z1.zs.u64[v] ^= P.zs.u64[v];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

This gives a considerable speedup, but I wondered if more optimized operations exist.
EDIT: I slightly improved the code by updating where to check the operator commutes, and performing some update as u64.

Yes, if you are ONLY SAMPLING, then you can implement an ignored-result $M_P$ more cheaply than what is done in the tableau simulator. In fact, I think it can be done even more efficiently than what you're suggesting.
To ignore-measure a Pauli product observable $P$, apply $P$ to the system as a correlated Pauli error with 50% probability. This randomizes all observables that anticommute with the measurement, enforcing Heisenberg uncertainty, which is all you need to really do. This is how stim.FlipSimulator (stim::FrameSimulator<W> in C++) does measurements (other than recording the result). It can actually be disabled via stim.FlipSimulator(disable_stabilizer_randomization=True), which is non-physical in that it lets you violate Heisenberg's uncertainty principle but is very useful for debugging or answering certain kinds of questions about error propagation through the circuit.
The reason the tableau simulator doesn't implement this method isn't just because stim Circuits don't have an "ignored measurement" instruction (though you can implement it by CX-ing the target qubit onto an unused ancilla then reseting the ancilla). It's because the specialty of the tableau simulator is to tell you properties of the state when doing a single shot. A randomized measurement strategy would defeat that use case. For example, if $X_q$ is a stabilizer of the state, and you ignore-measure $Z_q$ by stabilizer randomization then call stim.TableauSimulator.canonical_stabilizers, it will incorrectly report that $X_q$ (or $-X_q$) is still a stabilizer generator of the system.
Note: stim's source is C++20 so you can use std::popcount instead of bit twiddling like that. Also stim's "bag of bits" classes have template methods like simd_bits.for_each_word(simd_bits, simd_bits, func) for creating more efficient vectorized versions of the loops you are writing.
